# Passing an integer from user input to another class

Tags: java, string, parsing, user-interface, integer

I have a problem getting an integer passed from one class to another properly.

I'm creating a GUI that the user can input a number into a Text Field to resize a grid in a JPanel.

If I write it with an normal int just as below it works fine,

```
public int getGridSize() {
    return 6;
}
```

but when I try to change the code so it takes the String from the Text Field (default text in the field is the number "12") as follows.

```
private void initComponents() {

        gridPanel1 = new lizasummerschol.GridPanel();
        gridSize = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    gridSize.setText("12");
        gridSize.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                gridSizeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

 private void goBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
     size = Integer.parseInt(gridSize.getText());
     gridPanel1.executeUserCommands("reset"); 
     goB.setText("s "+size);
 }                                   


public void setGridSize() {
   this.size = size;
}

public int getGridSize() {
  if (this.size > 0) {
    return this.size;
  }
    else {
       return 10;
      }
}
```

The grid remains 10x10, regardless of what is input by the user, as if it isn't meeting the condition of being greater than 0.
The grid is generated in a JPanel called GridPanel. Here is the code that I think would be relevant.

```
package lizasummerschol;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
    GridJApplet myGridJApplet = new GridJApplet();    
    public int NUMBER_ROWS;
    public int NUMBER_COLS; 
public static int LEFT = 15;
public static int DOWN = 15;
public static int SIZE = 15;

    private int particleColour;
    private int fixedness;
    private int iteration;

    private Graphics bufferGraphics;

    private Image offScreenImage;
    private Image offScreenImageDrawed;
    private Graphics offScreenGraphics;
    private Graphics offScreenGraphicsDrawed;

private int [][] particle;
    private int [][] fixed;

    public GridPanel() {      
            addMouseListener( this );
    reset();
    }
    //Initialise particle with random colours

    private void initialiseRandomly() {
        NUMBER_ROWS = NUMBER_COLS = myGridJApplet.getGridSize();    
        particle = new int[NUMBER_ROWS][NUMBER_COLS];
        fixed = new int[NUMBER_ROWS][NUMBER_COLS];

      for ( int i=0; i < NUMBER_ROWS; i++ ) {
    for ( int j=0; j < NUMBER_COLS; j++ ) {
        if( Math.random()*3 < 1 ) {
            particle[i][j] = 0 ;
                            } else if ( Math.random()*3 < 2) {
            particle [i][j] = 1 ;
                           } else {
                               particle[i][j] = 2 ;
            }
                    fixed[i][j] = 0;
        }
       }  
    iteration = 1;
}
```

Is a string that has been parsed to an integer different from an integer? My thought is that it should take the "12" from gridSize when the applet initialises, and then when the text in gridSize is changed (and a "Go" button is pressed) it will redraw the GridPanel with the new dimensions.

Comment: That might not be the right way to put it, but what I mean is if I have a string myString = 6 and then go Integer.parseInt(myString), is that exactly the same as the integer 6, or is there some nuanced difference that is causing my problem.

Comment: If your String myString = "6", and you parse it, then it will be the int 6 and only the int 6, nothing more and nothing less. I'm afraid that your code and your post above is not giving us enough information to allow us to guess what your problem could be. I suspect that perhaps you're not parsing in an event listener such as  an ActionListener but rather in the class's constructor before the user has had a chance to interact with your GUI, but that's just a silly wild @ssed guess based on incomplete information. Please give more information so that we have a prayer of answering the question.

Comment: The class definition would work. Specially where you have defined `gridSize`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've added more code to my original question. Thanks for having a look. Does it make more sense now?

Ashwin, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Not yet. Where does `initialiseRandomly()` get called?

Comment: `initialiseRandomly()` is called in GridPanel, right after `public GridPanel()` See in new edit (sorry if I haven't shown enough, I didn't want to overload you with useless code)

Comment: I've seen your latest code edit. **Again**, where does `initialzeRandomly()` get called. Not sure if my question is clear.

Comment: No, you're showing where the method is defined, **not** where it's called. sigh. Again, where is there code that *actually calls this method*.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see what you mean. It's called by `reset()` 
It starts when the applet starts.

Comment: ***That's*** what I need to know! Please see answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I asked when your parsing is taking place, you state:

> It's called by reset() It starts when the applet starts.

Then it's as I suspected: you're calling `getText()` on a JTextField at a time when the GUI is under construction and way before the user has had any time to interact with the GUI. It makes sense that the text field will hold nothing of logical value at this time.

The solution is as I've stated in a comment above, to do your parsing in an event listener such as an ActionListener. This means that the parsing will take place when the user triggers an event such as pressing a JButton that triggers an ActionListener or when clicking on a JLabel and thereby triggering a MouseListener. This way you can get the information from the user when they've indicated that they've completed entering it, and that the calculation needs to be done.

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ParseTextFieldEg extends JApplet {

   @Override
   public void init() {
      try {
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               createGui();
            }
         });
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private void createGui() {
      ParseTextFieldPanel panel = new ParseTextFieldPanel();
      panel.reset();  // *** calling reset at the wrong time!

      getContentPane().add(panel);
   }

}

class ParseTextFieldPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton button = new JButton("Push Me");

   public ParseTextFieldPanel() {
      add(textField);
      add(button);

      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            reset();  // *** calling reset at the *right* time!
         }
      });
   }

   public void reset() {
      int myInt;
      try {
         myInt = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "myInt is " + myInt);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "myInt is not yet available or is a non-number");
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks! How would I go about parsing it in an ActionListener?

Comment: @user2077261: you'd parse it in an ActionListener the same way you're parsing it now, except that the code is called by the ActionListener's `actionPerformed(...)` method, and the ActionListener is added to a JButton or JTextField or other component that can accept it and can trigger an action. What part of this specifically confuses you? If you've tried this and get errors, then please edit your question, show your new code at the bottom and the errors, and let's try to work through it.

Comment: Can I do something like this? Only then then it sets it to 10 every time even after it has been started. I only want it to set to 10 when it starts up.
                                  
       `size = Integer.parseInt(gridSize.getText());` in the Action Event for a JButton.
        
Then a setter and getter?
`public void setGridSize() {
    this.size = size;
}
public int getGridSize() {
  if (size > 0) {
      return size;
   }
   else {
       return 10;
   }
}`

Comment: @user2077261: please show this code and question as an edit to the end of your original question. Code doesn't show well in comments. Also please let us know what happens when you try to do what you propose. Often times the best way to solve these things is to use your Java compiler as a laboratory where you experiment with different programs til you get it right.

Comment: Thanks for posting the example code =D
I thought there might be something simple along the lines of what I've shown in  my edit, but I am very, very new to Java, so most of the time, very wrong. =P Thanks for all your help

Comment: @user2077261: To be honest, I don't fully understand your comment. Again, please post it as an edit to your original question up at the top, and please elaborate on your explanation.